# AWS S3 exception when calling API from API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I'm facing this issue after deploying my React app to AWS S3 bucket using Code Pipeline.
Although this function works well in local environment, it still causes error on S3 hosting.
Further: I used AWS API Gateway for APIs and config that API URL in package.json like `"proxy":"https://linkgoeshere.amazonaws.com/dev`

[image: image here]

I tried to enable CORS by adding CORS in Permissions tab follow this guidance (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html) but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you could include details on your setup, what are you trying to do, etc.
Specifically how did you build the app? How did you setup S3 and the API gateway?
There are a few reasons you could get 404 error:

1. Your S3 bucket is not publicly accessible, so check your permission.
2. Make sure your API gateway is correctly configured to handle your app's requests.
3. Make sure your app is correctly configured to make request to the gateway

Comment: Thank you for your help 
These reasons don't seem to be the error causing this problem cause I can still access by not using proxy.